# Is it possible to return a list of superclass in the resource and receive the proper subclasses on the client side? (using resteasy)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy

I only get a list of instances of the superclass on the client side. I Hope jax-rs would dynamically create a list of different types including the type information of each object in the JSON of the object itself and then creates a list of the proper subtypes on the client side...

I guess its just no possible?! but don't get it why as if the type information is added to each object this could be done...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `jax-rs` is not the thing that automatically does anything. It's just an API, a contract between you and the webserver that runs your app. Your _implementation_ or `jax-rs` might be able to do what you ask without you lifting a finger, or it might not be. It depends on implementation. Most of them can also allow you to extend the implementation if they don't support what you need.

Comment: Im using resteasy both on client and server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer my own question if you are using resteasy with jackson for serializing your data to json and vice versa the following annotation on the superclass dto will do the trick:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include= JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
    property="__class")
```

Anyone using this keep in mind that this wont work if you return a list/collection of you dtos as jackson is missing the type information here and is not able to lookup the annotation as discussed here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/336
and can be solved easily by using a custom response dto owning the list of your dtos...